# How to get selected value from checkbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, insert-update

I have the following line of code in insert.aspx.

```
Source Code:
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludeSignature" runat="server" Text="Include Signature" />

Code Behind:
 command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IncludeSignature", chkIncludeSignature.Checked ? 1 : 0);
```

And this is the code for update.aspx:

```
Source Code:
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIncludeSignature" runat="server" Text="Include Signature" />

Code Behind:
 chkIncludeSignature.Checked=dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"].ToString();
```

I have inserted the checkbox value in db Table. I want the selected value in update form that i have inserted in insert form.i am getting the error as "Cannot convert type string to bool".

Comment: you can try this. `dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"].ToString() == "true" ? true : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chkIncludeSignature.Checked=dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"] == 1 ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  `.ToString()`  at the end of your last line of code. If `IncludeSignature`  is  `bit`  datatype in your db then `dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"]` must return a `bool` value. You can use `bool.TryParse(dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"].ToString(), out boolVariable);` as well.

Comment: IncludeSignature is of int type

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated this line...and its working fine..:)

```
chkIncludeSignature.Checked= Convert.ToBoolean(dtInvoice.Rows[0]["IncludeSignature"]);
```